# Spring Roo 2.0, release date, 2016?

Tags: spring-roo

Any  news about next release or roo 2.0-m2 or even better 2.0 m3? According informations from spring roo pages it could be probably in May but the project doesnt seemed to be very active. And what about milestone 3, is it going to be release in close future?[looking-ahead-to-spring-ro0-2](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/30/looking-ahead-to-spring-roo-2-0)

I would like to start new project and it is difficult to choose old roo version, which wont be probably in future supported, or new untested roo. 
It could help me to decide which way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the Roo 2.0 roadmap. Next release is [Roo 2.0.0.M2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO/fixforversion/15212/)

Comment: thanks, it is exactly what i need to know. There is a release date currently set to 12/May/2016

Comment: See [jira/ROO](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel) reports... the next version will be the [2.0.0.RC1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO/fixforversion/15810/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-development-integration-plugin:release-report-tabpanel)!